# MSSQL trigger on UPDATE: Support multiple row updates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have a SQL trigger that triggers on a table update. When the table is updated it modifies some fields in another table.

It seems to be working but I am not sure if the way I set status is correct (if inserted contains multiple rows). I tested it and got the correct answer (but still I suspect that this is not the correct/best way).

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[myTrigger]
ON [dbo].[myTable]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    declare @OldStatus int
    declare @NewStatus int
    select @OldStatus = [currentStatus] FROM INSERTED 

    if @OldStatus = 1 or @OldStatus = 3 or @OldStatus = 5
    begin
        set @NewStatus = 1
    end 
    if @OldStatus = 8 or @OldStatus = 9
    begin
        set @NewStatus = 8
    end
    if @OldStatus = 11 or @OldStatus = 12 or @OldStatus = 13
    begin
        set @NewStatus = 11
    end

    UPDATE myNewTable SET        [LastModifiedDate] = GETDATE(),
                                 [Status] = @NewStatus,
                                 [Type] = inserted.Type
    FROM inserted
    WHERE ([id] = inserted.id)
END
```

I'd think the correct solution would be something like:

```
UPDATE myNewTable SET        [LastModifiedDate] = GETDATE(),
                             [Status] = ***<add logic here>***,
                             [Type] = inserted.Type
FROM inserted
WHERE ([id] = inserted.id)
```

Comment: `select @OldStatus = [currentStatus] FROM INSERTED` >> This is wrong. You are assigning the last `[currentStatus]` as returned from the `SELECT` on `INSERTED` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[myTrigger]
    ON [dbo].[myTable]
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE 
        myNewTable 
    SET
        LastModifiedDate=GETDATE(),
        Status= 
            CASE 
                WHEN i.currentStatus IN (1,3,5) THEN 1
                WHEN i.currentStatus IN (8,9) THEN 8
                WHEN i.currentStatus IN (11,12,13) THEN 11
                ELSE NULL -- if the current status isn't in the cases above
            END,
        Type=i.Type
    FROM 
        myNewTable AS mnt
        INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON
            i.id=mnt.id;
END
```